# google chart slantedText and min Value is not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google chart. I want to slate text on x-axis and should be minimum value is 0 in y-axis. After some google i put some snippet not it working.

Here is my code:-

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(loadDaysLeadGraphData);
 var options = {
   hAxis: {
     title: "Month",
     textPosition: 'out',
     slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 90
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Revenue',
    minValue: 0,
    viewWindow: { min: 0 },
    format: '0',
  },
  height: 260,
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('days-leads'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are many options that simply do not work with *material* charts, including...

```
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.slantedText
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.slantedTextAngle
{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.minValue
```

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

*material* chart --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages:['bar']`

*core* chart --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages:['corechart']`

---

however, for *core* charts, there is an option for...

`theme: 'material'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var loadDaysLeadGraphData = [
    ['Year', 'Value'],
    ['2005',  58],
    ['2006',  63],
    ['2007',  66],
    ['2008',  66],
    ['2009',  81],
    ['2010',  85],
    ['2011',  86],
    ['2012',  86],
    ['2013',  89],
    ['2014',  90],
    ['2015',  90]
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(loadDaysLeadGraphData);
   var options = {
     hAxis: {
       title: "Month",
       textPosition: 'out',
       slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 90
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Revenue',
      minValue: 0,
      viewWindow: { min: 0 },
      format: '0',
    },
    height: 260,
    colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
    theme: 'material'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('days-leads'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="days-leads"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @WhiteHat, but it throw an error i.e, `Uncaught TypeError: google.charts.ColumnChart is not a constructor`. Actually i am using it anularjs controller and load google chart at once. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/SCHx1mQv

Comment: it should be --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- see answer above...

Comment: above `Uncaught TypeError: google.charts.ColumnChart is not a constructor` is throw when not load **bar** in `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']})`